# react native android initial request takes too long

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, reactjs, native

I have a strange problem. It only occurs on Android with an internet connection via Wifi. The initial request to my NodeJs server takes up to 50 seconds. The requests after that work normally
It does not happen when the device sends the request via mobile internet. It also does not occur on iOS devices.

Using:

- react-native: 0.62.2
- node: v12.13.0

sending requests like:

```
return fetch(`URL`, {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                Authorization:
                    `Bearer ${token}`
            }
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((json) => {
                return json            
            });
```

Comment: The handler's code on server side executes only after ~50s?

Comment: yes, it takes so long between sending from client and starting to process the request on the server side. The request itself is processed within 20ms

Comment: I think that's a security kind restriction. You could try set ```android:usesCleartextTraffic``` attribute to ```true``` in ```application``` tag in AndroidManifest. xml as solution for development environment. But for production the only way to solve is use https scheme instead of http.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but I already use https

Comment: if I send the request to my https api (https://api.domain.com) it takes that long via wifi. If I send the request to the api address only http (http://123.123.123.123:8080) it doesn't have any delay.

Comment: Are you sure you correctly setup https? Did you add certificate to your host?

Comment: yes, I have one from Let'sEncrypt and I have the Lock next to my domain. I use an NGINX as reserve proxy to my nodejs server. It's only happen on wifi that's the strange thing..

Comment: Same problem here. Using react@16.3.1, react-native@0.63.2, and expo@42.0.0. I am using https (with valid certificate). What I notice is that the first request to any domain takes a very long time.

Comment: I also have the same issue. Any fixes? Is it the server config problem or issue with react native?

Comment: It's been a while now, but the domain was not configured correctly.

Comment: I have the same issue. The first request takes a long time. @Stan can you explain what you mean by "the domain was not configured correctly" ?

Comment: Hi I have a similar problem, do you have an answer? Thanks